# From user's heading pointer to get location co-ordinate or placemark detail where user's face is in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit, locationmanager

Lets say I am getting the heading postion of user from Location manager "`didUpdateHeading`" but how I get the details of the place where user is heading/facing for example user is standing in front of statue of liberty(which we know theoretically) so how we get the co-ordinates or any placemark details of statue of liberty.

**So what I want to do is I want the placemark/landmark details where user's head is.**

Comment: You can get the location where the user is standing, means his current location

Comment: Yes Niraj, which I already mentioned, but how I get the landmark location or details where user is standing and facing ? i.e user is moving in highway, he stops and he watch any landmark, so he is facing the landmark and lets say this land mark is 20 meters away from the highway and user current position, but user is facing the landmark, so is there is any way we can get the location or any details of that landmark where user is facing ??

Comment: You can find the nearBy places using the radius

Comment: I just want to get the place detail where user is facing. I also edit my previous comment for more details.

Comment: you must take the Azimuth from real North, calculate the 'relative bearing' according to users Latitude line, then recursively increase the distance (like you said in 20m) from 0 to 20m, and in every step of iteration, get projections of relative bearing on Latitude and Longitudinal axises to generate new target location. on every generated target location you also need to make a hit test if is there a building in this iteration.

But before doing all of them, you should consider that iPhone Compass is still not reliable so much :)

Comment: @CoskunCaner Hey thanks for mentioning the term "relative bearing" thats what which can help me, It gives the right way for R&D so I am doing it. If you can tell me more info please you are welcome :)

Comment: @AG.29 Ofcourse, you must detect which semi-sphere user is staying on start. Like in the [Exemple Image](https://cdn.komensky.sk/thumb.php?server=svk&id=245631&type=4&thumb=1&ext=.jpg) You will need this when calculating iterations. On the north of the ekvator-line Latitude degrees will be positive, and in the south Lat will be negative; Similarly on the East of Greenwich, Longitude will be positive. Thats how you will decide to (add/remove) the projection segments for your target location's Estimated Lat&Long values. i suggest you just start typing your code, it will be more visible in time